# alertdialog when there is a missed call

Tags: android, alter

**alertdialog when there is a missed call**
I want to vibrate telephone when there is a missed call and display the dialogallert to stop the vibration

To use the dialog I'm using this code

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Call");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("show this?");

                            // "Yes" Button
                            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
                               {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked                        YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                            //  "NO" Button
                            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });


                            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: you need help to get miss call status help or anu issue with dialog ?

Comment: I want to vibrate telephone when there is a missed call and display the dialogallert to stop the vibration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the Event/Broadcast/Notification for Missed Call but you can get events of **ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED** from keep a track of events in this order
**EXTRA_STATE_RINGING** to **EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK** to **EXTRA_STATE_IDLE**

After this you can check Call Log and find the Missed Call detail.

For your connivance [here](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html) is the code sample for fetching Call Log

courtesy : AndDev.org

Comment: with that code so I can get all the missed calls?? because I want to detect if there is a missed call, unread
 at the end i want to vibrate telephone when there is a missed call and display the dialogallert to stop the vibration

Answer (score 0):

However, the design pattern you're trying to implement is not preferred.

Android itself will notify the user of a missed call. The phone will vibrate, based on the user's settings for vibration.

If you want to, you can check the call log yourself whenever you receive an ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED, and based on it, you should *send a notification*. Displaying a dialog is an annoying approach that interrupts the normal flow of tasks. You can implement a content Intent for the notification that sends the user back to your app when the notification is clicked. Once in your application, the user can choose to turn off vibration.

A missed call is usually not something that should interrupt other work the user is doing.

Comment: thanks!!
I can use Status Notifications instead of altertdialog but the problem is the same
I want phone vibrate when a call is lost and see the Notify to stop the vibration, practically the phone continues to vibrate (missed call) until it becomes "click" to notify.
NotificationManager are able to create it but I can not figure out how to detect the missed calls, 
sorry early ...